# CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install.
  You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
  This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
  This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. For more info, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293.
To re-install:
  sudo gem install cocoapods

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Comment: have you tried to run the command from the error message `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: Try same command    sudo gem install cocoapods still have same issue ,

Comment: flutter doctor                                
 
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.

Comment: I am using macbook air M1 chip. I am facing this issue since so long. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Just restarting the IDE worked..

Answer (score 173):

usually this happens due to visual studio or IntelliJ not able to find the path or associated plugin or extension.

here is the solution:

1. sudo gem uninstall cocoapods && sudo gem install cocoapods
2. restart IDE or Editor

the last step should solve the issue if not close the project entirely

Comment: Yes....I had run CleanMyMac X, but did not restart IDE afterwards. Restarting IDE seems to have worked.

Comment: Simply restarting my IDE fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks. Simply restarting IDE worked for me

Comment: Trick was to close VS Code completely, for me.

Comment: This does not work for me. Strangely enough, running `flutter run` and through Xcode works but not from Android Studio.

Comment: @Zenko SAME! It's the same for me. When I run the command ```flutter run``` from the command line it works too. But just not on Android Atudio.

Comment: @DeliciaFernandes do you know whats the reason? I am facing also same issue.

Comment: It is bad practice to install gems with sudo
Why? Because it means that you use system ruby, which you really shouldn't. And with ruby managers you don't need sudo for any gem installation to use sudo

Comment: Make sure to completely quit Android Studio. Just closing the window is not enough, you have to kill the app. If you're on Mac, you click on the dock and select "Quit".

Comment: most of the time I have to do the same. Do we have any other workaround?

Comment: Restarting Android Studio did the trick for me!

Comment: I my case didn't worked restart the IDE after uninstall and install cocoa pods.
But when I executed the `flutter run` command the error was displayed:
*Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update*

And executing `pod repo update` worked for me.

Comment: Once again this answer saved us :)

Comment: This is the shame, but restarting VSCode - helped... :facepalm:

Comment: Funny, I was configuring dev and prod flavors and had to add build phase runner script to detect the correct GoogleServices-Info.plist files, I guess that was probably the reason why, restarting VSCode works....... :)

Answer (score 115):

Someone I know had this issue, and another person recommended this fix.

Run this command from terminal:

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

The issue is that there are 3 possible resource paths where you put paths to your configs....

- 1<sup>st</sup> is the ~/.profile
- 2<sup>nd</sup> is the ~/.zshrc.
- 3<sup>rd</sup> is the ~/.bashrc.

So what happens is that when the path to your configs is not in the ~/.profile file, it can't be accessed from the opening link from the launchpad. Whenever you open a terminal session, all 3 paths are synchronised automatically. That's the difference.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I've installed Ruby with `asdf` and use `zsh` so I'm assuming one of the two of those caused this issue. Using `open` in terminal tells AS to use the correct path (for some reason).

Comment: Starting from the command line fixed the issue but I'm really curious how I can fix this for real...

Comment: Same thing, how to fix this for good? It's not a problem to run it from the terminal but....

Comment: Oddly enough running "flutter run" from the terminal in Android Studio works but click the play button does not.

Comment: I only update the flutter plugin and everything is fixed.

Comment: After running `open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app` once, in my case the paths seem to be fixed such that there is no need to run from command line again and running from the play button is fixed.

Comment: Worked for me '' open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app ''  thanks

Comment: Worked for IntelliJ Idea

Comment: This is working for me!!! I don't think I'm updating my Android Studio or doing anything different, but one day my Android Studio just stop being able to compile to iOS simulator and giving me the error above...

Comment: Thanks! Spent a few hours down a blackhole just for this to simply fix everything

Answer (score 46):

I had the same issue. Following worked for me

1. Clean project
2. Use terminal to run `flutter run`
3. It's an IDE related issue not flutter or cocoapods

Comment: Worked for me thanks

Comment: works like charm after replacing intel mac studio to m1 mac studio! thanks [:

Comment: `flutter run` works for me but not with Android Studio and I have no clue how to fix it now.

Comment: @Zenko Workaround is to start Android Studio via terminal: 
`open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

Comment: This works, but how can we fix it for good?

Comment: Don't works for me :(

Answer (score 38):

I was having similar issues. I just did the following things.

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. Reload VSCode
4. `flutter run`

Comment: After I did `flutter run` from the command line, it worked normally.

Comment: its works for me flutter run

Comment: Perfect ! simple asf and work like a god !

Answer (score 28):

This problem might be because you have multiple versions of cocoapods installed.

You can check and resolve it running:

- `gem list` check to see if multiple versions of cocoapod are installed
- `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` it will prompt you to select which one to uninstall, or if you want to uninstall all
- `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Additional step if you uninstalled all cocoapods

- Change to the iOS directory of your Flutter project
- `pod install`

That should then allow you to run an xcode build to an iOS device.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the editor if you modified the PATH variable COCOAPODS

Answer (score 25):

Reinstalling the flutter extension on visual code fixed this

Comment: ^ I look at this answer and try updating Flutter plugin on my IDEA. It works.
@MyKoryto it should not be in the comment.

Comment: it'w work also with AndroidStudio, i've had the same problem on Android Studio when i had updated my Xcode to Xcode 13.2, my project was run perfectly on Xcode but not in Android Studio

Answer (score 25):

On Android Studio, "Invalidate Caches / Restart.." worked for me.

Comment: cocoapods is for iOS, not Android.

Comment: @HammadKhan It is used via Flutter.

Comment: @DarShan yes per my understanding it is used only for iOS inside Xcode, not for Android. So Flutter will include cocoa only for iOS and not for Android because Xcode requires it.

Answer (score 22):

I spend about an hour trying everything here.

Finally, I figured out that on Mac you must quit VS code from the top menu and not just close the open windows.

Hopefully, it will save someone some frustration..

Comment: correctly, almost half day clean ad get... (:

Answer (score 19):

use `brew` to install `cocoapods`

1. `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
2. `brew install cocoapods`
3. `brew link --overwrite cocoapods`

if need unlink & link again `brew unlink cocoapods && brew link cocoapods`

Comment: Worked for my mac + android studio

Comment: In M1 Macbook and Xcode 14.1 it worked...
My issue was that I was able to run app from xcode but not from VSCode..
Note:- Use `Flutter doctor` to check if coacoapod is fine.

Comment: This worked for me. I was experiencing the issue described in the comments of other answers to this question; where running "flutter run" from the terminal in Android Studio works but click the play button does not.

Answer (score 14):

The following worked in my case:

```
brew install cocoapods --build-from-source
then: brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

More information about this issue can be found at:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8955

Comment: This will break any Fastlane builds just fyi.

Comment: I struggled for days to fix my broken cocoapods but this did it. Also, only use it as a last resort after everything else has failed.

Comment: @KennethMurerwa Glad, it worked for you!

Comment: that's what did it for me, too (didn't have to add `--build-from-source`, though. `gem install cocoapods` didn't work for some reason

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, I can run in xcode but not within vscode.
Following worked for me.

1. flutter clean
2. restart vscode

Answer (score 8):

Try with:

```
pod setup
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

after commands, restart IDE

Answer (score 7):

If you are using *Visual Studio Code* for Flutter development, the issue may be related to [Resolving shell environment fails](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_resolving-shell-environment-fails):

[image]

Many times, when running from UI (Spotlight, Dock, etc), *Visual Studio Code* fails to load shell environment variables on time (doesn't matter which shell you are using - `bash`, `zsh`, etc). As a result, the `PATH` and other environment variables are not loaded (properly) which can result in "**CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state**" error.

A workaround is to run *Visual Studio Code* from *Terminal* (instead of launching it from the UI) and then proceed with MacOS/iOS compilation as usual, i.e.

`open -a "Visual Studio Code"`

(or just `code` if you followed this [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_alternative-manual-instructions) and added *Visual Studio Code* to `PATH` environment variable)

❗️❗️❗️ No need for CocoaPods/Flutter plugin reinstall whatsoever ❗️❗️❗️

Answer (score 6):

I tried the solution proposed by heymonkeyriot, but that was not sufficient. What worked for me was uninstalling both cocoapods (respond Y when asked about deleting pods) ***and cocoapods-core***, then reinstalling cocoapods and running pod install:

```
sudo gem list
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Changed to ios directory for my project

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem while executing fastlane command.

Turned out that I installed fastlane using `brew` and cocoapods were installed with `gem`. Probably this is why `flutter doctor` show that everything alright, but when I tried to deploy app, fastlane failed with error above. Installing fastlane and cocoapods with: `sudo gem install fastlane; sudo gem install cocoapods` and removing both from homebrew resolved problem for me.

Basically make sure that you have both tools installed with the same package manager on macOS.

Comment: Those who are facing issues with fastlane, this is the fix.

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this,

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

And check,

flutter doctor

Answer (score 4):

In the terminal navigate to  your project root and enter:

`cd ios`

`pod install`

###### Note: Make sure to rebuild your project (in Xcode) before trying to run the application.

If this does not work, then try `brew install cocoapods` or `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using `fastlane` and still complaining about `cocoapods`, even `cocoapods` is installed properly, reinstall `fastlane` again:

```
brew uninstall fastlane
gem install fastlane
```

Comment: This one helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `bundle exec fastlane beta` command, make sure you've added `gem "cocoapods"` to your Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "cocoapods"
gem "fastlane"
```

Then execute:

```
bundle install
bundle exec fastlane beta
```

Answer (score 2):

On my mac after i installed a new ruby version (with RVM) seperately:

remove the ruby which was installed with RVM:

```bash
rvm list rubies
```

if it return:

```bash
ruby-3.0.2
```

enter:

```bash
rvm remove ruby-3.0.2
```

to remove the ruby version

then go to your flutter folder and in the terminal enter:

```bash
pod deintegrate
```

```bash
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
```

```bash
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf ios/Pods
```

```bash
pod deintegrate
```

```bash
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install ruby --latest
```

In my case the latest was 3.0.0

```bash
rvm use ruby-3.0.0 
rvm --default use 3.0.0
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

```bash
flutter clean
```

That fixed it for me!

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you need to install `cocoapods` using the `--user-install` flag.

Step 1: add this to your environment path. export

```
PATH=~/.gem/ruby/3.2.0/bin:$PATH    (remember to change your ruby version)
```

Step 2: install cocoapods

```
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

Source: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation

Answer (score 1):

After longer investigation, I identified **two error-causing points**.

#### Firstly,

Changing linker flags in `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` .
In Xcode, navigate to `Project Runner` -> `Build Settings` -> `Other Linker Flags` & change all the blob that there with:

```
$(inherited)
-framework
Flutter
```

[image: Other Linker Flags]

#### Secondly,

VS Code entry in my `PATH` variable was incorrect. After changing it accordingly to the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) he error was no longer present.

Comment: `PATH` is my case which after mac migaration.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with this issue with Android Studio, so i tried all of manipulations with gem and cocoapods stuff and it didn't helped. I fixed it with Android Studio settings: **File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart**.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar issue. Here's how to get around it.

1. Uninstall cocoapods, mentioned before but `gem uninstall cocoapods` just in case. Also the [cocoapods troubleshooting page](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting#installing-cocoapods) has a few steps to [look into](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting#im-getting-permission-errors-while-running-pod-commands).

Option 2.A - If you need the system ruby 2.6, in mac os 10.15, you can install an older version of cocoapods with this `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4`    source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384384

Option 2.B - If you can, install `rbenv`, with say ruby 2.7.2, set it `rbenv global 2.7.2` and then get the most recent version of cocoapods `gem install cocoapods`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading my Mac from older version to macOS Catalina 10.15.7. This failed.

```
flutter doctor -v
```

command. I tried many solutions but nothing worked. Finally, I solved by opening android studio and accepting the file access. After that

run `flutter doctor -v` command  and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

for me; reinstall ruby and cocoapods

```
rvm install ruby --latest
```

And

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Answer (score 1):

So after weeks and weeks of struggling with this issue, this is what worked for me as turns out a Ruby gem source was out of date (if you get a gem source related error when trying to install Cocoapods, you likely have the same issue):

1. Ensure that Cocoapods have been fully removed via: `gem list --local | grep cocoapods | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo gem uninstall`
2. List your current gem sources with `gem sources -l`
3. Remove any current sources which are causing an issue using `gem sources --remove URL_HERE`, such as `gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/`
4. Add this mirror instead `gem sources -a https://gems.ruby-china.com/`
5. If installing Cocoapods on a Mac before Mac OS X 10.11: `sudo gem install cocoapods`, if newer, use: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

That's it! A big thank you to https://www.programmersought.com/article/10015547501/

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling and installing cocoa pods the issue isnt fixed. Go into your ios folder delete the podfile.lock and run pod install inside the ios folder. Then completely quit and close your editor and start it again. Then try running the app again.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this every time I switch the branch of the Flutter project. I had to restart my VS Code (not just reload the window) completely - quit and open again for the Cocoapods error to be gone.

Here are the steps I used and worked:

1. Run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`
2. `cd ios` and run `pod install`
3. Quit and start VS Code

Answer (score 1):

If you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), *and* you followed the [docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation) and ran `sudo gem install cocoapods` then

```bash
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods && brew install cocoapods
```

`brew install cocoapods` pulls brewed `ruby` as a dependency, so if you don't already have the brewed ruby it will be automatically installed.

<sup>❗️During the ruby installation watch closely the log — it will display the extra path you need to add to your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` for example `/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH` (the correct path will depend on the type of mac you are using).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Same issue and fixed with the next steps:

1. pod install
2. restart vscode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For whom suffered for hours and none of the solution worked,
if you can run `pod --version` with issue, try

`sudo gem uninstall activesupport`
`sudo gem install activesupport -v 7.0.8`

then `pod --version`.
If that works, try `flutter doctor`. My XCode cocoapods issue is resolved after install different of activesupport.

Comment: this seems to have worked for me, though in order to uninstall activesupport I first had to uninstall `cocoapods-core`.  then I installed cocoapods with brew and `flutter doctor` now finds it.  incidentally `pod --version` seems broken.  I get some output but prefixed with the syntax for `grep` then a bunch of `connection refused` errors

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and this example from (https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) worked for me

```
$ cd ios
$ gem which cocoapods
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods.rb
$ /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/pod install
```

The issue for me was that although cocoa pods was installed, the `pod` executable was not on my path (apparently). Note that the pod install needs to be run from inside the ios directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by closing Android Studio and reopening it.  ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods latest version release depends on the new release of Ruby which does not work well with macOS mojave. All you have to do is to install lesser version of cocoapods.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

Try it out

Answer (score 0):

I use brew on macOS and following steps helped me -

1. start Xcode and close (this because Xcode may update itself)
2. brew update
3. brew upgrade
4. flutter upgrade (optional if there is a long gap or a stable update is available)
5. sudo gem update

Answer (score 0):

```
brew uninstall cocoapods
```

Apply the above command line, then restart the application Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything but in my case the real problem was that because I had 2 additional versions of ruby installed and was switching between them with `chruby` however, cocoapods were installed with `ruby 3.0.1` and had it set up in my `.zshrc` so that chruby would autmatically choose the right version of ruby which somehow did not work anymore on VS Code.

What I did to solve this was edit `~/.zshrc` by replacing `source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh` with `chruby ruby-3.0.1` after `source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh`.

This is only for people who use `chruby` !

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I uninstalled both **cocoapods** and **fastalane**, then reinstalled them.

Answer (score 0):

### for me works after open android stdio from terminal
Run Android Studio

open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

first check the ruby version ( command: ruby -v ) it should be the default version of macOS in my case it is ruby 2.6.10.

if you ruby version is not as the default then switch to the default version by command: rvm install "2.6.10"

then run flutter clean

after this you need to install cocapods by command: sudo gem install cocapods

finally command: flutter run and choose iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue after updating my MAC OS to Monterey 12.6.5,
So issue is with Ruby version, Please update the ruby to 3.1.3 , set it default. then run the cocoa pod install commands .
So follow below steps :

Move to Ruby 3.1.3

1. rvm install "ruby-3.1.3"
2. rvm --default use 3.1.3
3. Check the ruby version running : "ruby -v"
   it should display you 3.1.3
4. gem install cocoapods

and run your workspace

Dont install ruby 3.2.0 with Xcode 14.

Answer (score 0):

just change your cocoa pods version to 1.10.2 to solve your problem.

first, uninstall your current version (whatever it is)

In my case, i downgraded from version 1.11.3

```
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then install the stable version (as of Nov 11, 2021)

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods:1.10.2
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you switched from bash to zsh (or the other way around)
Check your global paths. Run `echo $PATH` to list them and look for `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

If missing you need to add it to `.zshrc` file or `.bash_profile` (whichever you are using now)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, that when I was download the new gems, I had a network outage and one of the .podspec files was not downloaded correctly.
In the middle of the json, it simply just stopped and was therefore an invalid token.

Once I found the correct podspec file, I simply had to delete it and run
gem install cocoapods again.

If you don't want to search the stecific file, you could also simply just go to the .cocoapods folder, delete all pods and install it again.

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I run first

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

or

```
$ gem install cocoapods --user-install
$ gem which cocoapods
/Users/eloy/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods.rb
$ /Users/eloy/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin/pod install
```

but don't work, because command tools of Xcode was not installed.
you should run

```
xcode-select --install
```

to install command tools of Xcode and then use brew or rvm , ... to install cocoapods.

commands for installing brew:

```
% /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

(echo; echo 'eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /Users/edvard/.zprofile
```

finally you can install cocoapods :

```
brew install cocoapods

pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter framework

just restart IDE like android studio with invalidate cash worked with me

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Just update Android studio on VMware MacOS worked for me

Comment: It could be a comment.

Comment: The answer could be comment.

Answer (score -1):

My Issue solve and working my project
Select gem to uninstall All cocoapods one by one package:

1. cocoapods-1.11.2
2. cocoapods-1.11.3
3. cocoapods-1.12.0
4. cocoapods-1.12.0

## And intsall

sudo gem install cocoapods,
sudo gem install rails