# Please tell me when I upgrade Cocoapobs from 1.11.1 to version 1.11.2. Then I can't run the app on Simulator ios anymore

Tags: flutter

[Please tell me when I upgrade Cocoapobs from 1.11.1 to version 1.11.2. Then I can't run the app on Simulator ios anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdYDO.jpg)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state.)

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.