# Android studio "flutter run" working but Run button not working

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, cocoapods

When I click the android studio run button, I get the following error and no matter how many methods I tried, it doesn't work, but when I type the "flutter run" command, it works.

> Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
> CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
> Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
> For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
> To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

Exception: CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale
tr-TR)
• Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/aksoyhlc/flutter/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 77d935af4d (6 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
• Engine revision 890a5fca2e
• Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
32.1.0-rc1)
• Android SDK at /Users/aksoyhlc/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• Aksoyhlc iPhone’u (mobile) •----- •
ios            • iOS 14.7.1 18G82
• Chrome (web)               • chrome                                   •
web-javascript • Google Chrome 97.0.4692.99

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue sometimes, the only way i found was to uninstall cocoapods, reinstall it and relaunch the IDE. Check the steps todo here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64000509/9043877