# CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state. Error when running the project directly from the button running android studio (green button)

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, dart

[image]I have a flutter project, it runs smoothly when running project from terminal with "flutter run" command. however, get an error when running project directly from android studio running button (green button).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Oke I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

You don't have cocoapods installed while you probably make use of pods in your code. Check the documentation: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html