# Flutter: How to solve this Cocoapods version problem?

Tags: flutter

The App is working perfectly on Android but on iOS it shows me this Error when I try to launch:

```
Warning: CocoaPods minimum required version 1.9.0 or greater not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

And I'm actually shocked by this Flutter command of Cocoapods version 1.9.0! because I have just installed the latest Cocoapods version which is 1.5.2 on GitHub through brew install cocoapods.

Did someone face this problem before?

Please help :'(!

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by:

1. Uninstall Hebrew completely from Mac.
2. Install rvm.
3. Install latest ruby version through rvm.
4. Install cocoapods---> sudo gem install cocoapods.