# Flutter Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install - Mac Book M1

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, apple-m1

I have been struggling now already for 8 month with my Mac Book with M1 Chip and really need to find a solution now.
The Cocopods just don't work

```
Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install.
  You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
  This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
  This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
```

What I did so far:
Re installing Coco Pods, starting the IDE from Command Line and reinstalling pods.
See here : [CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state)
I don't think its related to my Android Studio version.

```
which pod
```

/usr/local/bin/pod

**flutter doctor -v**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 11.5.1 20G80 darwin-arm, locale en-ES)
    • Flutter version 2.10.5 at /Users/timknogel/FlutterDev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (8 days ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/timknogel/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.66.0)
    • VS Code at /Users/timknogel/Desktop/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.38.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 13 (mobile) • 3253AB15-FB90-45F5-93CD-5A95FC029075 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 100.0.4896.127

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Can anybody help?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved it?

Comment: No :( I opened a threat on Github swell but nobody is responding: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11369

Answer (score 0):

what about this: [CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state)
it like a similar error.

on my case:

1. switch to best ruby version: `rvm --default use 3.1.2`
2. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
3. or `brew install cocoapods`
4. `pod repo update`
5. restart IDE

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**follow theese steps:**

1. `sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.6`
2. `sudo gem install cocoapods`
3. `cd ios`
4. `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, was to set a global ruby version using **rbenv** or **rvm**, because for some reason, flutter defaulted to using system ruby which was different from what was being set in my .zshrc file. Which caused the version mismatch for cocoapods.