# CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state. Error launching application on iPhone 12 when flutter run on ios simulator

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, ios-simulator

Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 12.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state - There are lots of solutions here

Answer (score 0):

I tried running `flutter doctor`,everything was okay.
So I found another solution.

1. Close android studio
2. Open android studio through the terminal

`open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

3. Open your project again and run ,it works.

I hope someone finds another solution. because this always happens.