# Flutter installation into MacOS | Cocoapods installation error

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.1.1

I am trying to install flutter into my macOS 13.1 (22C65). I have already installed flutter and Xcode. But I cannot install cocoapods.

After I ran "flutter doctor" to check if anything is left to install, it told me to install cocoapods. But when I run "sudo gem install cocoapods", it shows me the following error message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5QN3.png)
How can I fix this?

I tried running this`sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc`  and installed 1 gem. But after I run `flutter doctor`, it says I still have to install cocoapods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state)

Comment: your answer is here already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593939/cocoapods-not-installed-or-not-in-valid-state

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

1. `sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.4`
   2.`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Then, run `flutter doctor` to check. It works.