# Xcode Errors when running Flutter run

Tags: flutter, macos

These are the errors I'm currently facing when running my program:

```
Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/mustafa/Downloads/Flutter%20Starter%20Template%20/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRe
gistrant.h:9:8


Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header
'/Users/mustafa/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ebkdimfgzvdbnvbwufevtglbxn
zo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_3LFM7Q
FA8RRIV-clang_32ZU5P1SDEB18.pch' for bridging header
'/Users/mustafa/Downloads/Flutter Starter Template
/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'
```

I have tried everything from deleting ios file to using flutter pub upgrade and even re-starting VS Code and I'm still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

after deleting ios folder run this command `flutter create .`
and then run `pod install` and then check platform ios version in podfile

Comment: I did that it still didn't work so I deleted the entire file and i'm redoing the terminal commands again to see if I get the same issue again

Comment: I faced same issue try to install cocoapods using sudo gem install cocoapods and it failed 
Then I tried using VPN because these CDNs was restricted in Egypt
Do the following:
gem list check to see if multiple versions of cocoapod are installed
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods it will prompt you to select which one to uninstall, or if you want to uninstall all
sudo gem install cocoapods
Additional step if you uninstalled all cocoapods

Change to the iOS directory of your Flutter project
pod install
That should then allow you to run an xcode build to an iOS device.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62871473/13537720